# Write a For Loop that goes through categories of a dataset and returns a vector that calculates the number of times the category appears

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I have a vector called "catNames" that takes all unique categories from a data set and lists these in alphabetical order. I am looking to create a for loop to go through "catNames" and calculates the number of times the category appears in a new vector. This is how I started and I know the first line is accurate but I cannot get it to populate with the number of times the category appears in the data set.

```
numAuctions = rep(NA,length(catNames))
for (i in 1:length(catNames)) {
  numAuctions[i] = sum(auctionData$Category == catNames)
}
```

I am looking for a solution that returns a vector with the number of times the category appears.

```
numAuctions
5 10 12 7 8 etc
```

Comment: I think that `dplyr::count()` or `table()` on the original data vector `auctionData$Category` would be better ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Create a toy dataset

```
# first vector
fruits <- c("apple", "banana", "cherry", "date", "elderberry", "fig")

set.seed(0)

# second vector
example <- sample(fruits[1:5], replace = TRUE, size = 100) # 1:5 because I want to exclude the last one, for the example
```

2. Turn the second vector into a vector of factors, using the categories from the first vector

```
example <- factor(example, levels = fruits)
```

3. Call table() on the second vector

```
table(example)
```

Output:

```
     apple     banana     cherry       date elderberry        fig 
        22         22         16         19         21          0
```